# Mathematica on Linux Ubuntu: antialiasing issue

Tags: linux, antialiasing

I'm working on a webMathematica application using a linux server (Ubuntu 12.0.4 LTS) with Xtightvnc. Even though the system administrator has done all the possible to set the anti-alising features, we get a poor quality images.
Here is an example of code and related results:

```
image = Style[TraditionalForm[f[x] == (x^2 + 3)/(x - 1)], 50, FontFamily -> "Times New Roman"];
Developer`UseFrontEnd[Export["test.png", image, "PNG", Background -> None]]
```

here are the results we get
In Linux
[image]

and here is the same on a Windows server
[image]

We also made tests with RealVNC, with the same results.
The only way to get a better image is to logging into the console of the web server machine from another machine with an X server running. But, this is not a valid approach, because we have to keep alive the session using a PC only for that. 
We read many other posts about anti-aliasing configuration for Linux, here on stackexchange and somewhere else, with no avail.
Is there anyone experiencing the same problem? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Add `, FontSize -> actual*100` and then scale the image down using either mathematica or `ffmpeg`

Comment: Thanks, this is a possible solution I found looking at other posts, however I'm not sure the quality we get is the same as the Mathematica built-in anti-aliasing. Moreover, it is very bothering to manage font size for different objects, like like subscript, superscript, ticks on graphics, grids, and so on. On the other hand, I didn't find anyone saying anti-aliasing is not available for Mathematica on Linux (even if is frequently mentioned as something very critical).

Comment: I thought so.  My solution is to run mathematica in a virtual machine in xp on linux.  I find the linux mathematica to be to glitchy.  You might have to get creative if you don't have an xp key lying around.